# Equivalent code for System.Security.Cryptography in Java

Tags: java, c#, .net, encryption

I'm trying to convert the following C# code to Java, the code is using .NET library (System.Security.Cryptography), I want a work around to get the same results using Java:

```
internal static class CryptoHelper
{
  // keys must be 16 characters long (and ASCII)
  public const string DefaultKey = "2$8Kba19z23asd!#";
  public const string IV = "0000000000000000";

  enum CryptoTransformType
  {
     Encryptor,
     Decryptor
  }

  public static byte[] Encrypt(bool FIPScompatible, string key, byte[] data)
  {
     if(key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
     if(data == null) return null;

     // Create the crypto
     ICryptoTransform transform = CreateCryptoTransform(FIPScompatible,CryptoTransformType.Encryptor, key, IV);

     // Encrypt the data
     using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
        using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
           cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        }

        byte[] encryptedData = ms.GetBuffer();
        return encryptedData;
     }
  }

  public static byte[] Decrypt(bool FIPScompatible, string key, byte[] data)
  {
     if(key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
     if(data == null) return null;

     // Create the crypto
     ICryptoTransform transform = CreateCryptoTransform(FIPScompatible,CryptoTransformType.Decryptor, key, IV);

     // Decrypt the data
     using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
     {
        using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
           byte[] decryptedData = new byte[data.Length];
           cs.Read(decryptedData, 0, decryptedData.Length);

           return decryptedData;
        }
     }
  }

  private static ICryptoTransform CreateCryptoTransform(bool FIPScompatible,CryptoTransformType transformType, string key, string iv)
  {
     if (!FIPScompatible)
     {
        RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
        rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        rijndael.BlockSize = 128;

        byte[] bykey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        byte[] byiv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);

        ICryptoTransform transform = null;

        if (transformType == CryptoTransformType.Encryptor)
           transform = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(bykey, byiv);
        else
           transform = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(bykey, byiv);

        return transform;
     }
     else
     {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        provider.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        provider.BlockSize = 128;
        byte[] bykey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        byte[] byiv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);

        ICryptoTransform transform = null;

        if (transformType == CryptoTransformType.Encryptor)
           transform = provider.CreateEncryptor(bykey, byiv);
        else
           transform = provider.CreateDecryptor(bykey, byiv);

        return transform;
     }
  }      
 }
```

I tried a method but I couldn't get the same results that comes out from the .NET code, the method I tried will be added in the comments.

Comment: Don't add the method to the comments, add it to the question.

Comment: You should always try to search Google/SO before asking the questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113113/interop-encryption-decryption-between-java-net-with-aes-and-specifying-iv-and-ke